# Issues with MultiValuedMap declaration

Tags: java

I'm facing an issue with the MultiValuedMap declaration. When I tried to define the following, I'll get an error "MultiValuedHashMap cannot be resolved to a type".

```
MultiValuedMap<K, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<K, String>();
```

I have already downloaded the Apache Commons Collections 4.1 jar.

Is there any mistake which I've done?

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct imports?

Comment: @fabian Where are you searching? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html

Comment: @cricket_007 the one in JavaEE has different capitalization (a lowercase v instead of uppercase), this one should be from the Apache Commons Collection (according to the line after the code)

Comment: @UnholySheep Ah, so we are looking at [Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html)?

Comment: The import I have is `import org.apache.commons.collections4.*;`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project and then "Clean", I had the same issue...

Comment: I have tried that, but I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

MultiValuedHashMap class is not present in Commons Collections jar.
Try including javax.ws.rs-api-2.0 jar to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

since you mentioned Commons Collection 4.. is it not like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiValueMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap;
...
MultiMap<String, ?> map = new MultiValueMap<>();
```

That's assuming you need MultiValueMap. Otherwise MultiValuedHashMap is in jersey?